# Applying insertion sort to arrays of objects

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compareto, insertion

I'm trying to apply insertion sort to an array of objects but my else if never compiles and says "bad operand types".

Just wondering if I need to make a very specific `compareTo` method or if there's a better way of comparing arrays of objects in an insertion sort method.

EDIT:

So here's me trying to use my `compareTo` method and it compiles but I get a `null pointer exception` on the `else if`. Why?

```
public static void insertElement(WordClass[] Words, int next)
{
    WordClass value = Words[next];
    int i = next;

    while(true)
    {
        //
        if(i == 0)
        {
            Words[0] = value;
            break;
        }

        else if(Words[i-1].getStr().compareTo(value.getStr()) <= 0)
        {
            Words[i] = value;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Words[i] = Words[i-1];
            i--;
        }
    }
}


public static void insertionSort(WordClass[] Words)
{
    for(int i = 1; i< Words.length; i++)
    {
        insertElement(Words, i);
    }
}

     //in WordClass
     public int compareTo(WordClass w) //makes WordClass comparable
{
    return getStr().compareTo(w.getStr()); 

}
```

Comment: Words[i-1] == (value) <= 0    ,,,,, this is the problem

Comment: == either return true or false

Comment: So how can you check say , true is less than or equal to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use `campareTo` instead of `==` or `<=` operators for object types, unless you want to campare two object variables to see if both refers to same object. 
Also your `WordClass` class must implement the `Camparable` interface in order for this to work.

Comment: I've made an edit using compareTo if someone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it